# Renewing provision profile

Tags: ios, certificate

My distribution certificate and provision profile are shown expired in my developer account.
I have regenerated my distribution certificate.
Now if I edit provision profile which uses new distribution certificate will it require to resubmitting app to app store?

Comment: no, the future ones wil only have to be submitted with new provsioning profile

Comment: my expired provision profile will affect existing app on appstore?

Comment: no, the app will continue working with the old provisioning profile because it is prsent in the embedded.mobileprovision of the binary that you submit

Answer (score 1):

No, Not need to resubmit an app to App Store.

Once you regenerated the certificates, apple will automatically updates the associated apps which are already uploaded. So, you don't worry about that. But, be updated to upload the next version or new app.

Comment: my expired provision profile will affect existing app on appstore?